# How to create a RegExp from its string representation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, literals

I have a string containing a regular expression in literal notation, e.g.:

```
var pattern = '/abc/i';
```

How can I create a regular expression object from that string?

Of course, I could just use `eval`:

```
eval(pattern); // /abc/i
```

But I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Are you sure the string will always be a regex?

Comment: Uh, `new RegExp(pattern)` ? -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's supposed to be a regex, but it could contain a typo.

Comment: @adeneo that gives me `/\/abc\/i/`

Comment: So write valid patterns

Comment: _but it could contain a typo_ can you provide example @Stefan

Comment: @SagarV it could inadvertently lack the opening `/`, i.e. `abc/i`. A broken regex doesn't have to be repaired, but it should not crash my program – `eval` would result in a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: abc`

Comment: @Stefan do you want to accept such typos that is also want to change it to regex or avoid that?

Comment: @SagarV it would be sufficient if I could determine if the provided string is a valid regex.

Comment: @Stefan I would like to ask one more q. did you consider `abc/i` as valid or not.

Comment: @SagarV not valid :-) I would probably throw an appropriate "regex is invalid" exception in that case.

Comment: @Stefan a slight issue with previous one. I updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do something like this:

```
var pattern = '/ab*c/gi';

if ((m = /^\/(.*)\/([gim]*)$/i.exec(pattern)) != null) {
   restr = m[1], flag = m[2], re = new RegExp(restr, flag)
}
//=> /ab*c/gi
```

You may need to add handling of special regex meta characters if you want them to be treated literally.

Comment: Escaping is not needed, the characters should be treated just like a regex literal. However, wouldn't it be easier to use capturing groups in order to match both parts at once, e.g. `/^\/(.*)\/([gim]*)$/.exec(pattern)`?

Answer (score 2):

I just created a function for that. Check it.

- Substring from 1 ( to avoid first `/`) to last index of `/`). -> we got the pattenr.
- substring from last index of `/` +1 to string length -> got the flags

Then pass the 2 arguments to the `new RegExp` function

```js
function formRegEx(str){
  var reg=str.substring(1,str.lastIndexOf('/'));
  var flags=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1,str.length);
  return new RegExp(reg,flags);
  
}
console.log(formRegEx('/abc/i'));
console.log(formRegEx('/[a-zA-Z]/ig'));
```

### Update

From OP's comment on question, `abc/i` may present which should be treated as invalid.

So, a test can be done to check the validity

```
/^\/.*\/[igm]*$/
```

and then check for no existence of `//` by testing against

```
/[^\\]\/[^igm]/
```

The above function can be rewritten as

```js
function formRegEx(str){
  if(!/^\/.*\/[igm]*$/.test(str)) return "Invalid RE";
  if(/[^\\]\/[^igm]/.test(str)) return "Invalid RE";
  var reg=str.substring(1,str.lastIndexOf('/'));
  var flags=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1,str.length);
  return new RegExp(reg,flags);
  
}
console.log(formRegEx('/abc/ig')); // true
console.log(formRegEx('/abc//i'));  // false
console.log(formRegEx('/a/bc/i')); //false
console.log(formRegEx('/[a-zA-Z]/ig')); // true
console.log(formRegEx('abc/ig'));  // invalid
console.log(formRegEx('abci')); // invalid
console.log(formRegEx('/abc/ik')); // invalid
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combo of `substr` and `lastIndexOf` like this:

```js
var pattern = '/abc/i';

// the index of the first "/" is always 1
var index = pattern.lastIndexOf('/');          // index of the last "/"

var thePattern = pattern.substr(1, index - 1); // the actual pattern part
var theFlags   = pattern.substr(index + 1);    // the flags part

var regex = new RegExp(thePattern, theFlags);

console.log(regex);
```